# open a doc in firefox automatically

Tags: 2010, office-integration, powerpoint-services

I am trying to automaticly open an office doc (word/excel/ppt/...) from sharepoint while using Firefox browser in the browser. 
I manage to so manually (do manually what my method (written in C#) soppose to do) - 
so i figure that all the settings [the feature "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" is DEACTIVATE ] in the sharepoint are ok - I can open the doc in the browser just by clicking on it.

Comment: your question sounds confusing, can you please explain it properly :)

Comment: to make myself clear - I am trying to automaticly open an office doc (word/excel/ppt/...) from sharepoint while using Firefox browser **in the browser**.
I manage to so manually - so i figure that all the settings in the sharepoint are ok - I can open the doc in the browser just by clicking on it, the feature "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" is DEACTIVATE. thanks

Comment: I understand it like the following. You wan't to display the doc (ppt, word etc.) in the page. Rendered as doument. This will work in IE without problems to set the mime type of the response to "application/word" or s.th. I don't know if firefox support it, to render a document inside (out of the box). in c# doesn't exis any method like "file.PleaseDisplayMe()" :). you must only set the mimetype in the response. So it's brwoser specific.

Answer (score 1):

*Open Documents in Client Applications by Default*  - settings just works for files that can be rendered in the browser like (swf,txt). However opening MS Office based through SharePoint is a different thing.

For Excel to open in your browser through SharePoint document libraries you must enable Excel Service Applications at the farm level.

For rendering word and powerpoint files you need Office Web Apps integrated with SharePoint 2010.

I am not really sure, but Firefox do have some limitations rendering office documents which you get in technet reference for known browser limitations for SharePoint 2010. But unless you have Office Web Apps you cannot open a powerpoint file through sharepoint.

Comment: The problem is that : if I do it manually (what the method soppose to do) it works fine. It open the ppt doc in the browser...BUT while I try to do it automaticlly, than the problems starts

Comment: I'm really sorry but your comment is not completely comprehensible for me to suggest a corrective action on the same.

Comment: i will try again : "open document in client applications by default" is inactive. when i open the ppt doc (just clicking on it in the home site) it opens in the browser, like i want it to do. when I run my function - that soppose to do the same - it try to open the doc in the client computer.